# How to reset the resource of image view in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to change the image in imageView dynamically based on the status.

Image changed successfully but problem is walk image overwrite on the run image. I want to clear the existing image and then set the new image.

`status_image.setImageResource(if(runningState == RunningState.FAST) R.drawable.ic_run_fast else R.drawable.ic_walk)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it with a "0" parameter before doing anything else:

```
status_image.setImageResource(0)
```

Comment: But here setImageResource() function wont accept null as it accepts non-null type Int only

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was answering from my memory; try edited version

Answer (score 1):

Nullability of drawable content is your friend, AndroidDocs nailed it: [setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

So in your case `statusImageView.setImageDrawable(null)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `ImageView` to transparent. Then change it back to the resource you want.

```
status_image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Another option is to use some third party lib to handle the images for you as well, like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).